# Finding front-end IP addresses for cloudflare websites

Tags: dns, ip

I'm trying to set up my VPN to allow certain websites to bypass it. My VPN only allows the bypass list to have entries based on IP address, not domain name. I tried to ping the sites in question and enter the IP addresses I got from that, however I quickly realized that by virtue of them using Cloudflare, it wasn't a viable option.

Is there a way for me to get a list/range of the the IP addresses that a Cloudflare site uses? Or is there some other workaround I can use in my case?

Comment: https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/

Comment: @SathyajithBhat I don't want to allow all Cloudflare sites to bypass the VPN, though

Comment: you don't have a choice because the website can be assigned _any_ IP from CF's IP range.